# Titanium Studio javascript - Adding to an Array

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

How can i go about adding to an array on button click, i have a table view which is my array, what i want to do is have another piece of data added to that table view when i click a button on another screen.
This is how i have made my tableview.

```
var customTableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
BackgroundColor:'White',
style: Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewStyle.GROUPED,
search:search,
searchHidden:true,
data:[
{title:"Toms List", value: true},
{title:"Shopping List", value: true},
{title:"Jocelyns List", value: true},
{title:"Friday List", value: true}
]
```

});

Thanks for any help <3

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I have a table view which is my array"...a TableView is a View object not an array. Do you mean you want to append a row to an existing tableview? If so, use the appendRow method http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView If not....please clarify :)

Comment: hey sorry for not being clear, i have posted some code showing how i made my tableview if this clarifies it more.

Comment: hmm ok, you can still just call appendRow() "Each row can be passed as a TableViewRow object, or as dictionary specifying the properties for a table row, in which case this TableView will create TableViewRow objects as needed."

Comment: ...if you want to push data to your data array, do it like "data.push({title:"Friday List", value: true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to @phil comment, you can get your current tableview data, add your new row, then reset the tableview data:

```
var data = customTableView.data;
data.push({title:"Toms List", value: true});
customTableView.data = data;
```